# How do I capture and view ITM trace information on a Cortex-M4 MCU?

Tags: embedded

I would like to capture, decode, and view ITM trace information for a Cortex-M4 MCU (in my case, an Atmel SAM4S).  In particular, I want to capture exceptions and user trace data relative to other signals on my board (i.e. show all signals and trace information on same timeline).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using the following steps:

1. Place debugger in SWD mode.  If using J-Link Segger on Linux, this can be done with `JLinkGDBServer -if swd`
2. Add code to the MCU to enable trace.  Set the bit rate to a value suitable for your needs (I used 8 MHz).  Example Ada code is below.
3. Use logic analyzer to capture trace data on TRACESWO line from SAM4S processor.  I used a Saleae Logic Pro 16 with 100 MHz sample rate.
4. Convert the data to a format usable by sigrok.  Using the Saleae to capture the data, this comprises the following steps:

   - Capture using only the first 8 channels (so one byte per sample is exported).
   - Export data as binary to `trace.bin`, writing a byte for every sample.
   - Convert to a trace.sr file using:

     `sigrok-cli -i trace.bin -I binary:samplerate=100000000,numchannels=4 -o trace.sr`
5. Open the `trace.sr` file in PulseView.
6. Add UART decoder to TRACESWO channel, bit rate 8000000.
7. Stack ARM-ITM decoder.

See http://www.sigrok.org/blog/new-protocol-decoders-arm-tpiu-itm-etmv3 for more information.

Example Ada code for SAM4S Trace:

sam4s-trace.ads:

```
with Interfaces;

package SAM4S.Trace is
   pragma Preelaborate;

   type Channel_Type is new Integer range 0 .. 31;
   type Value_Type is new Interfaces.Unsigned_32;

   procedure Initialize;

   procedure Put (Channel : Channel_Type;
                  Value   : Value_Type);

   procedure Put (Channel : Channel_Type;
                  Message : String);
end SAM4S.Trace;
```

sam4s-trace.adb:

```
with System;
with System.Storage_Elements; use System.Storage_Elements;

package body SAM4S.Trace is
   procedure Initialize is
      ITM_LAR : Interfaces.Unsigned_32
        with Address => System'To_Address (16#E000_0FB0#), Volatile;

      ITM_TCR : Interfaces.Unsigned_32
        with Address => System'To_Address (16#E000_0E80#), Volatile;

      ITM_TER : Interfaces.Unsigned_32
        with Address => System'To_Address (16#E000_0E00#), Volatile;

      ITM_TPR : Interfaces.Unsigned_32
        with Address => System'To_Address (16#E000_0E40#), Volatile;

      DEMR : Interfaces.Unsigned_32
        with Address => System'To_Address (16#E000_EDFC#), Volatile;

      TPIU_SPP : Interfaces.Unsigned_32
        with Address => System'To_Address (16#E004_00F0#), Volatile;

      TPIU_FFCR : Interfaces.Unsigned_32
        with Address => System'To_Address (16#E004_0304#), Volatile;

      TPIU_ACPR : Interfaces.Unsigned_32
        with Address => System'To_Address (16#E004_0010#), Volatile;

      DWT_CTRL : Interfaces.Unsigned_32
        with Address => System'To_Address (16#E000_1000#), Volatile;

      use Interfaces;

   begin
      --  Enable write access via the Lock Access Register.
      ITM_LAR := 16#C5AC_CE55#;
      --  Enable the ITM, enable SWO mode behavior, enable synchronization
      --  packets, enable DWT event submission, enable timestamps.
      ITM_TCR := 16#0001_001F#;
      --  Enable access in user mode to all 32 channels.
      ITM_TPR := 16#0000_0000#;
      --  Enable all 32 trace channels.
      ITM_TER := 16#FFFF_FFFF#;

      --  Set TRCENA bit to 1 in Debug Exception and Monitor Register.
      DEMR := DEMR or 16#0100_0000#;

      --  Select NRZ serial wire output.
      TPIU_SPP := 16#0000_0002#;

      --  Deactivate formatter.
      TPIU_FFCR := 16#0000_0100#;

      --  Set prescalar (/10).
      --  TPIU_ACPR := 16#0000_0009#;

      --  Set prescalar (/15).
      TPIU_ACPR := 14;

      --  Enable exception trace and exception overhead.
      DWT_CTRL := DWT_CTRL or 16#0005_0000#;

   end Initialize;

   procedure Put (Channel : Channel_Type;
                  Value   : Value_Type) is
      Port_Reg : Value_Type with Address => System'To_Address (16#E000_0000#) +
        4 * Channel_Type'Pos (Channel), Volatile;
   begin
      --  Port register lsb is set when the the FIFO can accept at least one
      --  word.
      while Port_Reg = 0 loop
         null;
      end loop;
      Port_Reg := Value;
   end Put;

   procedure Put (Channel : Channel_Type;
                  Message : String) is
      Port_Reg : Value_Type with Address => System'To_Address (16#E000_0000#) +
        4 * Channel_Type'Pos (Channel), Volatile;
   begin
      --  Port register lsb is set when the the FIFO can accept at least one
      --  word.
      for Index in Message'Range loop
         while Port_Reg = 0 loop
            null;
         end loop;
         Port_Reg := Value_Type (Character'Pos (Message (Index)));
      end loop;
   end Put;

end SAM4S.Trace;
```

Answer (score 6):

As you tagged it with "logic analyzer", this may be off-topic, but I found the following extremely helpful. With Keil uVision (and probably with other IDEs as well) you can reroute ITM data to file using a custom .ini file.

Enable SWJ in your debugger, use SW Port. Enable Trace, enable the stimulus ports that you want to use.

Write a .ini file with an content like this:

```
ITMLOG 0 > "debug.log"
ITMLOG 1 > "testlog.xml"
```

This wil reroute ITM channel 0 to a file named "debug.log", and channel 1 to "testlog.xml" (file syntax from [here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_cm_itmlog.htm)).

To use the channels easily with fprinf in you c-code I use following setup:

```
struct __FILE { int channel; };
#include <stdio.h>

#define ITM_Port8(n)    (*((volatile unsigned char *)(0xE0000000+4*n)))
#define ITM_Port16(n)   (*((volatile unsigned short*)(0xE0000000+4*n)))
#define ITM_Port32(n)   (*((volatile unsigned long *)(0xE0000000+4*n)))

#define DEMCR           (*((volatile unsigned long *)(0xE000EDFC)))
#define TRCENA          0x01000000

int fputc(int ch, FILE *f) {
  if (DEMCR & TRCENA) {
    while (ITM_Port32(f->channel) == 0);
    ITM_Port8(f->channel) = ch;
  }
  return(ch);
}
```

And usage within the project:

```
FILE debug_stream = { .channel = 0 };
FILE test_stream = { .channel = 1 };

int main(void) {
    fprinf(&debug_stream, "this is a debug message, it will be rerouted to debug.log");
    fprinf(&test_stream, "this is a test message, it will be placed in testlog.xml");
}
```

Reference: [link](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/ulink2/ulink2_trace_itm_viewer.htm)