# Is there a way to send data directly to the JTAG port from application? (Cortex-M3)

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-m, nxp-microcontroller, jtag

I'm using an NXP LPC1769, which contains a Cortex-M3. So far, I've only been accessing it from the JTAG interface, but now I have to do it the other way around. An IT routine is supposed to read certain parts of the memory, and immediately send them out to the JTAG port. Is there a way to do this?

*UPDATE: After hours of research, I found something that might help: Cortex-M3 supports ITM (Instrumentation Trace Macrocell), which can send data through the TDO pin of the JTAG port. My question now is, how would one go about doing so? I only found debugger-specific applications of the ITM, where in my case, I want to be able to send specific JTAG messages (or write specific DP/AP registers) from the running application.

Comment: I answered another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123443/how-do-i-capture-and-view-itm-trace-information-on-a-cortex-m4-mcu/32123445#32123445) which may be of use for you. It is especially targeted at the keil IDE, but the ITM part should be what you are looking for. What I don't know ist how to extract the ITM information on PC side. There must be a Doc with your debugging tool. Maybe you find something there.

Comment: First off I doubt this is jtag, but instead SWD, subtle difference, sure.  It is a master slave thing, like spi, i2c, usb, etc.  You want to "send" something to the master, you leave it somewhere and have the master poll for it.  If it were truly JTAG, this would still be the case, the master drives the clock and the jtag state machine tdo is a slave to that, you place the values in a register in the jtag space and then have the master poll it.

Comment: Read your arm documentation where these topics are covered.

Comment: It is JTAG, believe me. My code handles the navigation through the TAP state machine by bit-banging the individual JTAG signals, and it wouldn't work if it was SWD. I am currently using the polling solution you mentioned, but the very reason I'm looking for an alternative is that the polling is too slow for my application.
I understand that JTAG is primarily a master-slave thing, and it is not meant for the target to send data to the host, but I was hoping there was a way.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can do host I/O over the JTAG port. The first one I normally turn to is called semihosting. Semihosting uses processor breakpoints in order to provide the debugged board with IO to the host. The mechanism is explained a little more here: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0471h/Bgbjjgij.html.

How you might enable semihosting on your debugger will change based on what tool you're using. For example, a thread for setting up semihosting in the LPCXpresso IDE can be found here: https://www.lpcware.com/content/forum/configure-lpcxpresso-use-semihosting and a guide for GNU Arm Eclipse can be found here: https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/09/11/semihosting-with-gnu-arm-embedded-launchpad-and-gnu-arm-eclipse-debug-plugins/.

The downside to semihosting is that it is *slow* when compared to using ITM.

Another method, as you allude to in your question, is by using the ITM (Instrumentation Trace Macrocell) functionality. Unlike semihosting, the ITM can operate without waiting for the JTAG adapter to poll it for data if the SWO pin is enabled or a separate UART output has been configured. As with semihosting, the details will change based on the tools you're using.

A guide for using ITM as a standard output in the LPCXpresso IDE can be found here: https://www.lpcware.com/content/faq/lpcxpresso/how-use-itm-printf.